# Python3 virtual env not working as expected

Tags: 12.04, python3

Long story short, i've setup a virtual environment using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04) but whenever i run the command `which python3` i get the system wide python, rather than the virtual env python.

This is where my Env resides:
[image]

After running `source Documents/RedRiverWorld/CapricornEnv/CapricornEnv/bin/activate` then `which python3` i get ...
[image]

This is clearly not my virtual env python3. What is the problem?

Comment: not sure this will help, what does return the command `which -a python3`? Shoud return all directories with python3.
And after reading the tutorial, I’m not sure you have any problem at all, you have the (CapricornEnv) prefix that indicate you are working in this environment.

Comment: After inputing your command, one directory outside the environment, i got:   1) /usr/bin/python3 and 2) /bin/python3

Comment: Hi, I did the same to test, an I can get the same result by modifying the activate file. Can you check the activate file (in your case should be Documents/RedRiverWorld/CapricornEnv/CapricornEnv/bin/activate (by modifying the first one, I get usr/bin/python3, but can be necesary to check all)), line 40 VIRTUAL_ENV="path" where path should be the path of your virtual environment.